# Add the years to the column and summarize the value in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below

```
cust start-dt    end-dt      item item_type sales cost trans-dat
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx 1500  1400 08-01-2019
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx 2000  1600 09-01-2019
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx 2500  1000 07-12-2019
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx 1600  1300 05-01-2020
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx 2400  1700 02-01-2020
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx 2200  1300 04-01-2020
```

I need to convert to year wise data as below. 
based on the customer and the item they bought across every year

```
cust start-dt    end-dt      item item_type  year sales cost
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx  2019 6000  4000
A    07-01-2019  07-01-2020  AA   xxxxxxxxx  2020 6200  4300
```

i tried melt and cast but melt doesnt create new columns/rows.

this data is only an example. I have multiple customers and multiple items for every customer and the start and end also differs for every cust.

Please guide me on how to approach the issue.

Comment: Is the `year` column the year of the `start-dt`, `end-dt`, or `trans-dat`? And you want to summarize the `sales` and `cost` columns? By summing them?

Comment: The year column is the years between start-dt and end-dt.  Consider it like a membership for the customer. but the sales and cost are summed based on the trans-dt which is basically the transaction date. The trans-dt will always be between the start-dt and the end-dt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `year` in the result is from the `trans-dt` column. So you need to extract that year and do a grouped sum. Here's a `dplyr` method:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(year = as.integer(substr(`trans-dt`, 7, 10))) %>% # chars 7 to 10 as the year
  group_by(cust, `start-dt`, `end-dt`, item, item_type, year) %>%
  summarize(sales = sum(sales), cost = sum(cost))
```

See the [FAQ on summing by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061) for additional info.